# Stripe API request using VueJs

Tags: api, request, vue.js, stripe-payments

I am making the following get request using vuejs:

```
this.$http.get(`api.stripe.com/v1/search?query="+email"` ).then((response) => {

            console.log(response)
        })
```

the problem is that this request is pointing to:
http://localhost:8000/api/api.stripe.com/v1/search?query=%22+email%22

And I need to point to:
https://api.stripe.com/v1/search?query=%22+email%22

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use .get(`https://api.stripe.com/v1/search?query="+email"`)?

Comment: It did not work the first time. But now it does. Rookie mistake. Thank you.